# Creating multiple non-overlapping rings but unable to tell which fc they surround using ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, buffer

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.4.

I would like to create multiple ring buffers surrounding my polygon localities. My buffers should not overlap and I need to know, which location each of my buffers surrounds.

I've thought to simply use `arcpy.MultipleRingBuffer_analysis`. However, if I use `Dissolve_Option = "NONE"`, I am able to define which locations my buffers surround, as the locations ID is stored in newly created `"ORIG_FID"` field. However, my buffers overlap.

If I use `Dissolve_Option = "ALL"`, my buffers do not overlap. But, I have no information about which location does my buffer surround.

How do I accomplish having multiple distances non-overlapping buffers but be able to know the location they belong to?

My code to create multiple ring buffers:

```
# Import modules
import arcpy, os

# Set environmental settings
inWD = "C:/Users/Localities"
arcpy.env.workspace = os.path.join(inWD, "analyzed.gdb")
outPath = os.path.join(inWD, "output.gdb")

# Allow files to overwrite
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Define input variables
inFC = "NPR"

try:

    # Define Multiple ring buffer variables
    distances = [100, 500, 1000, 2000]
    buffUnit = "Meters"
    Field_Name = "distance"
    Dissolve_Option = "ALL"
    Outside_Polygons_Only = "OUTSIDE_ONLY"


    # Process: Multiple ring buffer
    outBuff = os.path.join(outPath, "buff_complete")
    arcpy.MultipleRingBuffer_analysis(inFC, outBuff, distances, buffUnit,
                                      Field_Name, Dissolve_Option,
                                      Outside_Polygons_Only)
except:

    print(arcpy.GetMessages(0))
```

Simple illustration for distances [100,500,1000,2000] Meters: even if I click only on 100 m buffer (the closest to inFC), my buffers have to overlap, as in attribute table I've selected 3 different buffers.

[image]

Comment: What do a couple of your input features and output buffers look like?  A picture should help.

Comment: Just leave the buffers undissolved and erase the overlaps.

Comment: how can I erase the overlaps please? Please, be more specific. I have Advance licence

Comment: 100 m should not be erased. 500 should be erased with 100 buffer, 1000 erased with 500, 2000 erased with 1000. For example use Select by attributes and Erase then merge the outputs together.

Comment: I see. but is there a way to make it in "nicer way", bot to erase them one by one? I have too many features...

Comment: You dont need to manually select every feature, use select by attributes and three erases. Or do you mean you have different feature classes of buffers? Or dissolve the buffers and use Spatial Join to add the attributes lost in dissolve.

Comment: Hi @BERA, why did your answer disappear? Your approach actually solved my problem! Can you put it back that I can accept it?

Comment: It was untested so i removed it thinking someone else would post an answer. Nice, i have undeleted it.

Comment: but it works well :D thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont dissolve the buffer, just erase the overlaps. Add this after buffer:

```
outerasedbuffer = 'outerasebuffer'

for d in distances:
    if d==100:
        sql = """{0}={1}""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(datasource=outbuff, field='distance'),d)
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_features=outbuff, out_layer='lyr_100', 
                                         where_clause=sql)
    if d==500:
        sql = """{0}={1}""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(datasource=outbuff, field='distance'),d)
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_features=outbuff, out_layer='lyr_500', 
                                          where_clause=sql)        
        arcpy.Erase_analysis(in_features='lyr_500', erase_features='lyr_100', 
                            out_feature_class=r'in_memory\buff500')
    if d==1000:
        sql = """{0}={1}""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(datasource=outbuff, field='distance'),d)
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_features=outbuff, out_layer='lyr_1000', 
                                          where_clause=sql)        
        arcpy.Erase_analysis(in_features='lyr_1000', erase_features='lyr_500', 
                             out_feature_class=r'in_memory\buff1000')
    if d==2000:
        sql = """{0}={1}""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(datasource=outbuff, field='distance'),d)
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_features=outbuff, out_layer='lyr_2000', 
                                          where_clause=sql)        
        arcpy.Erase_analysis(in_features='lyr_2000', erase_features='lyr_1000', 
                             out_feature_class=r'in_memory\buff2000')
arcpy.Merge_management(inputs=['lyr_100', r'in_memory\buff500',r'in_memory\buff1000',r'in_memory\buff2000'], output=outerasedbuffer)
```

Or dissolve the buffers and join the attributes back using Spatial Join.

Comment: how would you go about doing the erase if there were about 100+ buffers?